# I am very stuck with this Kata... need to return an array of the even and odd numbers split into two

Tags: arrays, split, numbers, return

Write a function that takes an array of numbers and returns a new array of arrays containing the numbers split in two. Even numbers should return a pair of the halved number; odd numbers should return the integer either side of the halved number.

```
function splitNums(numbers) {}

const numbers = [4, 6, 7, 9, 99]

splitNums(numbers) // [[2, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [49, 50]]
```

Comment: Can you provide *any* details as to what you are "stuck" on?

Comment: I have tried to start with declaring a new variable = [], then have tried to new array.push math.floor(numbers.length/2) and Math.ceil(numbers.length/2) but i'm not sure how to put this together in a map function

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry forgot to tag

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial use of `map`:

```
function split(nums) {
    return nums.map( function(n) {
        return n;
    } );
}
```

Which applies the function to the each value in `nums`; since it just returns the value, you get back your original list.

So you'll need to replace `return n;` with what you *actually* want to replace each element of `numbers` with.